# compare same case class data from an array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, case-class

I have a case class as below :

```
  case class bar(id:String, name : String, gender : String, dob : String)
```

And sample data as below :

```
val barList = Array(bar("1", "ABC", "M", "2000-06-06"), 
                    bar("2", "DEF", "F", "2009-11-12"), 
                    bar("1", "GHI", "M", "2002-06-30"), 
                    bar("2", "JKL", "F", "2008-10-30"))
```

Now I want to get max and min dob of persons name based id

```
  def getMaxDOBName(id :String) = {  val idarray = barList.groupBy(_.id)(id).sortBy(_.dob); idarray(0).name  }
  def getMinDOBName(id :String) = {  val idarray = barList.groupBy(_.id)(id).sortBy(_.dob); idarray(1).name  }
```

I am getting below output :

```
scala> getMaxDOBName("1")
res16: String = ABC                 // wrong 

scala> getMaxDOBName("2")
res17: String = JKL              // wrong
```

Do I need to convert dob to date format then do sorting, or can we get any simple way ?

Comment: Does the apache-spark tag mean that the solution can make use of Spark? Or how does come spark into this picture here?

Comment: @mike I am using this code snippet in spark environment, even we can try with spark too. If we have any approach to do in easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `maxBy` and `minBy` with `filter`:

```
def getMaxDOBName(id :String) = barList.filter(_.id == id).maxBy(_.dob).name
```

Also personally I would say that converting string to actual date will be more correct approach in general case.